# Как добавить кнопку Run в show line numbers секции в Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

Друзья, никак не могу понять, как добавить кнопку Run как на скриншоте. Помогите сделать также[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ThdL.png)